# How can I convert a specific part of a map to an image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

If I am using MapView, and want to convert the view to an image where each corner is a map point (zoomed default by the map), how could I do this? (not asking for code, just some direction). I do not want to save the image, but simply get the image matrix to use in computer vision, all quickly and dynamically in the same program. I cannot rely on taking screenshots.

Hope this helps others too - really have looked everywhere but no luck.

Cheers

Comment: You can use `MKMapSnapshotter`

Comment: Wow. amazing. Sounds perfect. How does it output?

Comment: It gives you an `MKMapSnapshot` object which is a wrapper around a `UIImage` with some additional functionality to convert between lat/lng coordinates and points in the image.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MKMapSnapshotter is what you're looking for. Here is an example in Swift:

```
let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
options.region = mapView.region
options.size = mapView.frame.size
options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/snapshot.png")

let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { snapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        print("Snapshot error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapshot.image)
    data?.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)
}
```

If your interested in reading more about MKMapSnapshotter check out [this NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/) post. In the post there is an example of how to draw an annotation on the image, which I have used before in an app and it works well.

Hope that helps!